# Matrix for Mixed Boundary Value Problem

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

My friend and I have been working on numerical solving the following equation $$-u'' = f$$ with $x \in [0,1]  $ ,  $ u'(0) = 0$, $u(1) = 0$.

Analytically, we found the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions $\lambda_n = \frac{(2n-1)\pi^2}2$ and $y_n(x)= cos(\frac{(2n-1)x\pi}2)$

But we don't know how to find the right matrix for a finite difference method havign discretized the Neumann condition as $U_0 - U_1 = 0$

Can anyone provide some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you have the difference equation
$$\frac{U_{i+1}-2U_i+U_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2}=-\lambda_nU_i$$
The Neumann boundary condition is the same as having the mirror image of the solution on the other side of $x=0$. Thus one could assume $U_{-1}=U_1$ and the left boundary difference equation reads
$$\frac{2U_1-2U_0}{(\Delta x)^2}=-\lambda_nU_0$$
**EDIT**: Come to think of it, that isn't very accurate. If you start with
$$\begin{align}U_0&=U_0\\
U_1&=U_0+hU_0^{\prime}+\frac12h^2U_0^{\prime\prime}+\frac16h^3U_0^{\prime\prime\prime}\\
U_2&=U_0+2hU_0^{\prime}+2h^2U_0^{\prime\prime}+\frac43h^3U_0^{\prime\prime\prime}\end{align}$$
Then, since $U_0^{\prime}=0$
$$8U_1-U_2=7U_0+2h^2U_0^{\prime\prime}$$
So a better difference equation would be
$$\frac{-7U_0+8U_1-U_2}{2(\Delta x)^2}=-\lambda_nU_0$$

Answer (score 0):

Before you connect your analytic analysis to FDM scheme, here is FDM Scheme to solve the Poisson equation in one dimension.j

Let $x_0=0$ and $x_5=1$ with uniform step size $\Delta x$.

For $i=1, 2, 3, 4$,
\begin{equation}
 -u''(x_i) = \frac{-U_{i+1} + 2 U_{i} - U_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2} + o(\Delta x^2).
\end{equation}

In particular, $i=0$, (at Neumann boundary condition node, $x_0$), 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{-U_{1} + 2 U_{0} - U_{-1}}{\Delta x^2} = \frac{-U_{1} + U_{0}}{\Delta x^2}
\end{equation}
since $U_0-U_{-1} = 0$.

Therefore your matrix system will be
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\Delta x^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 U_0\\U_1\\U_2\\U_3\\U_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 F_0\\F_1\\F_2\\F_3\\F_4
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}